# Interactive choropleth map not rendering properly in Streamlit app when changing filters

Tags: python, streamlit, folium, choropleth

I have developed an interactive choropleth map using Streamlit and folium. The map allows users to filter data using dropdowns for the year and region, as well as sliders for other parameters (Image 1). However, I've noticed that sometimes, when I change the year, region, or rank filters, the map doesn't render properly within the Streamlit app (Image 2).
Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2
[image: Image 2]

This function displays the folium map:

```py
def display_map(year, region, start, end, _geo_data, data):
    df = filter_data(data, year, region, start, end, 'Happiness Score')
    if df.empty:
        st.warning("No data available for the selected filters.")
        return "", "", ""
    
    myscale = get_scale(df, 'Happiness Score')
    map = display_choropleth_map(_geo_data, df, myscale)
    st_map = st_folium(map, width=700, height=450)
    country = ''
    happiness_rank = ''
    happiness_score = ''
    if st_map['last_active_drawing']:
        properties = st_map['last_active_drawing']['properties']
        country = properties.get('name', '')
        happiness_score = properties.get('happiness_score', '')
        happiness_rank = properties.get('happiness_rank', '')
    else:
        country = df["Country"].iloc[0]
        happiness_rank = df.loc[df["Country"] == country, "Happiness Rank"].iat[0]
        happiness_score = round(df.loc[df["Country"] == country, "Happiness Score"].iat[0],2)
    return country, happiness_rank, happiness_score
```

Here choropleth layer is added:

```py
@st.cache_resource(hash_funcs={folium.Map: lambda _: None})
def display_choropleth_map(_geo_data, df, myscale):
    x_map = 17.51
    y_map = 22
    map = folium.Map(location=[x_map, y_map],
                     zoom_start=1, tiles=None, scrollWheelZoom=False)
    folium.TileLayer('CartoDB positron', name="Light Map",
                     control=False).add_to(map)

    choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
        geo_data=_geo_data,
        name='Choropleth',
        data=df,
        columns=['Country', 'Happiness Score'],
        key_on="feature.properties.name",
        fill_color='YlGnBu',
        threshold_scale=myscale,
        fill_opacity=1,
        line_opacity=0.2,
        legend_name='Happiness Score',
        smooth_factor=0
    ).add_to(map)

    def style_function(x): return {'fillColor': '#ffffff',
                                   'color': '#000000',
                                   'fillOpacity': 0.1,
                                   'weight': 0.1}

    def highlight_function(x): return {'fillColor': '#000000',
                                       'color': '#000000',
                                       'fillOpacity': 0.50,
                                       'weight': 0.1}

    df_indexed = df.set_index('Country')
    for feature in choropleth.geojson.data['features']:
        country = feature["properties"]['name']
        feature['properties']['happiness_score'] =round(df_indexed.loc[country,
                                                                  'Happiness Score'],2) if country in list(df_indexed.index) else 'N/A'
        feature['properties']['happiness_rank'] = int(
            df_indexed.loc[country, 'Happiness Rank']) if country in list(df_indexed.index) else 'N/A'

    NIL = folium.features.GeoJson(
        choropleth.geojson.data,
        style_function=style_function,
        control=False,
        highlight_function=highlight_function,
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
            fields=['name', 'happiness_rank', 'happiness_score'],
            aliases=['Country: ', 'Happiness Rank', 'Happiness Score'],
            style=(
                "background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;")
        )
    )
    map.add_child(NIL)
    map.keep_in_front(NIL)
    return map
```

The error in console when the issue is happening this:
[image: Console]

The full code of the project is added here: https://github.com/NirmalSankalana/happiness-insights/blob/main/home.py

I suspect this issue might be related to caching, but I'm not entirely sure. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?